# Pyfolio - drawdown table

Tags: python

I would like to view the drawdown table. When I use `create_returns_tear_sheet` get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddOzb.png)

How can I export or create only a **drawdown table**?

I try:

```
In: perf_func2 = timeseries.get_max_drawdown
    perf_stats_all2 = perf_func2(returns=ret)
    perf_stats_all2

Out: (Timestamp('2010-04-23 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
     Timestamp('2010-05-07 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
     Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'))
```

Thanks, for your help.
I apologize for my English language.

Comment: `pf.show_worst_drawdown_periods(ret)`

And now, I don't know how to export to pandas or excel/CSV file.

Any ideas?

Comment: `def get_max_drawdown_underwater(underwater):
.
.
.
 return peak, valley, recovery
def get_top_drawdowns(returns, top=10):
.
.
.
 return drawdowns
def gen_drawdown_table(returns, top=10):
.
.
.
 return df_drawdowns
def show_worst_drawdown_periods(returns, top=5):
.
.
.
import empyrical as ep
dd = gen_drawdown_table(strategy,5)`

Done. Please close.